# Replace a word with a symbol in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql, regexp-replace

I need to replace a word with `•` but I need to count before the length of the world because I have to hide only a half of the word

```
question -> ques••••
World -> wor••
```

Any ideas please?

Can the `regex_replace` function be the solution?

I tried

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('Stack Overflow','(\w)\w','\1*'), '\*\w', '**') 
FROM DUAL;
```

This is what resulted

```
S•••• O•••••••
```

What I want as result would be:

```
Sta•• Over••••
```

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible with regex. Write a PL/SQL function instead and loop through your string.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Well, how to answer this? Do you know PL/SQL? It is Oracle's programming language built into the DBMS. You can write a function that accepts a string and returns a string. You can loop through the string character by character, or maybe you find a way to loop through it word by word. Then do your processing and create the output string.

Answer (score 1):

See if this option helps.

Sample string:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Stack Overflow' from dual),
```

Split it to words (separated by space character):

```
  3  temp as
  4    -- word-by-word
  5    (select        regexp_substr(col, '[^ ]+', 1, level) word,
  6            length(regexp_substr(col, '[^ ]+', 1, level)) len,
  7            level lvl
  8     from test
  9     connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ' ') + 1
 10    )
```

Mask the last part of every word and aggregate the result back:

```
 11  select listagg(substr(word, 1, trunc(len/2)) || lpad('*', len - trunc(len/2), '*'), ' ')
 12    within group (order by lvl) result
 13  from temp;

RESULT
----------------------------------------
St*** Over****

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the original separators present between the original words:
(you may also use trunc() instead of round() in the calculation of the splitting length, but words of 1 char will be lost)

```
with data(id, s) as (
    select 1, '2 questions' from dual union all
    select 2, 'A World    of ... questions' from dual union all
    select 3, 'Stack, Overflow' from dual
)
select id, 
    listagg( rpad( substr(target,1,round(length(target)/2)),length(target),'*') || sep ,'') within group(order by lvl) as result
from (
    select id, level as lvl, 
        regexp_substr(s,'[^[:punct:][:space:]]+',1,level) as target,
        regexp_substr(s,'[[:punct:][:space:]]+',1,level) as sep
    from data
    connect by level <= regexp_count(s,'[[:punct:][:space:]]+') + 1
        and prior id = id
        and prior sys_guid() is not null
)
group by id
;

1   2 quest****
2   A Wor**    o* ... quest****
3   Sta**, Over****
```